# Secure screenlocking with X and tty login

Tags: linux, login

I choose not to run a login manager on my systems, instead opting for a tty login and then invoking xinit manually (slightly long story, it makes my life a lot easier to have a bunch of environment tweaks that my login shell sets up and has the rest inherit), but this leaves me with a security issue if someone else comes upon my PC, because even if I've locked my X session they can switch to a tty and kill my X session, dropping back to a shell.

I can either

1. Start running xinit; logout (which still has a race condition issue, if they get another Ctrl+C in before logout is invoked it'll give a shell)
2. Try to disable the tty switching keys in X
3. Wrap xinit in something to catch and ignore the signal from the Ctrl+C

Or some better solution that I've not considered.

Comment: I think if they have your computer they can do a _lot_ more than just killing your x session.

Comment: Sneaking in a hardware keylogger comes to mind...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `exec xinit` will *replace* your shell process with `xinit`; it remains killable, but if it is later killed, you get dropped to the login screen.
- `setsid xinit; logout` or `(xinit &); logout` will start *xinit* in background and then end the tty session immediately. This is even better – X11 cannot be ^C'ed anymore.

  (Such combinations as `exec setsid xinit` *may* work, I haven't tried.)

<sub>FWIW, some login managers *do* read "environment tweaks" from the standard `~/.profile`; I know GDM does.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for multiple great answers! I like the fork xinit and logout option especially, I think this is what I will use.

WRT login managers doing environment tweaks, my profile checks to see if we're SHLVL=1 and if we are goes off and does a whole bunch of stuff that I'm not sure will work with GDM/etc.

Comment: GDM uses `sh`, true, but it's still fine for such things as environment variables. Checking SHLVL in `~/.profile` isn't really necessary, since the file is normally read by login shells *only* (unlike `~/.bashrc` or `~/.*rc`, which apply to all shells).

Comment: My machine is possibly incorrectly configured, as `.profile` is read by new terminals, and even by new sessions inside tmux.

Comment: @Richo: It seems tmux creates login shells by default :( (`set -g default-command bash` is a workaround.) Terminals normally do *not* do it by default, but each terminal program has its own configuration. You were probably right in checking $SHLVL...